# POSIX: strtod - question

Tags: perl, string, posix, strtod

Can someone explain me, how `strtod` works resp. why I get here `10,2` despite the `en_EN`-locale?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use POSIX qw(locale_h strtod);

setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, 'en_EN.UTF-8' );

my $str = '5,6';

$! = 0;
my ( $num, $n_unparsed ) = strtod( $str );

if ( $str eq '' or $n_unparsed != 0 or $! ) {
    die "Non-numeric input $str" . $! ? ": $!\n" : "\n";
}

say $num + 4.6;

# 10,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISO 3166 identifier is wrong. Try `US`.